# Why does plotly express throw out data points on a timeline?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, plotly

I have a simple dataframe with two columns. A sample is shown below, the [data is available here](https://pastebin.com/x164p1Zp).

```
   year-week  users
0    2018-22      2
1    2018-23      3
2    2018-24      4
3    2018-25      3
4    2018-26      5
..       ...    ...
69   2020-03    232
70   2020-04    226
71   2020-05    214
72   2020-06    203
73   2020-07    119

[74 rows x 2 columns]
```

When I try to plot those two columns with Plotly Express, it omits the data until `2019-30`.

```py
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/x164p1Zp")
fig = px.line(df, x="year-week", y="users")
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%Y-%W"))
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly]

If I plot the same data with matplotlib, the data is shown:

```py
import pandas
import matplotlib

df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/x164p1Zp")
df.plot.line(x="year-week", y="users");
```

[image: matplotlib]

I cannot understand why two plotting libraries show the same data in a wildly different way.

How can I plot all the data points in Plotly Express to get a plot similar to what matplotlib shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotly does not recognize your x axis as being a date.
You need to convert it explicitly to a datetime format.

**Solution:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/x164p1Zp")
# convert column to datetime, weekday needed for conversion to work
df["year-week"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year-week"] + '-0', format="%Y-%W-%w")
fig = px.line(df, x="year-week", y="users")
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%Y-%W"))
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly result]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, when I try to convert year-week `2018-08` to datetime (with the `pd.to_datetime...` code) I get `2018-08-05`. Why is it picking the 5th day?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand what it's doing. It first adds a weekday to the the yearweek `2018-31` so it become `2018-31-0` (Sunday of week 31 in 2018). Then it converts to/looks up a `YYYY-MM-DD` date of that specific Sunday, which is 2018-08-05.